# How to Wrap Text in Excel Using Python win32com

Tags: python-2.7, word-wrap, win32com

I've been pouring over the web these last couple days to try to find a text wrapping method using win32com.client with python 2.7.2 (text wrapping as in wrapping the text in a single cell like you would to when you right click and do it in the Format Cells dialogue box).

Something like:

```
sheet.Cell(1,1).Font.WrapText = True
```

I've found a thread doing some finda nd replace stuff that includes wrapping I think [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-October/064831.html) but I believe this is for word wrapping in MS Word.

I tried the methiod used [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=888927) as well, but I'm getting an error indicating WrapText does not exist. I've just doing a quick report and exporting the results to an excel spreadsheet and the word wrapping would bea  nice feature to have!

Answer (score 1):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.wraptext.aspx you would use

```
sheet.Cell(1,1).WrapText = True
```